# ASP.NET Core API post action always has invalid ModelState

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .net core webapi project which has a POST action on a controller, which has a(n obfuscated) signature like:

```
    [Route("person/{Id}/media")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Media media, Guid Id)
```

Media is an abstract class representing the base class of either a BookMedia or a MovieMedia.  When I make a call to the method via postman, media is null, and the output windows shows this message:

```
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executing action method OurApp.Api.Data.Controllers.MediaController.Post (OurApp.Api.Data) with arguments (, 7c39c945-d0a5-433f-98bd-e044f4b87723) - ModelState is Invalid
```

The Media class is decorated with a JsonConverter which successfully performs its function, returning a Target object of the correct concrete class, regardless which type of Json is sent in.

The Model Objects look something like this.

```
Abstract Class Media
+ MediaId
+ PersonId
+ virtual Person
+ Title
+ CreatedDate_Internal
+ ModifiedDate_Internal
+ Deleted_Internal

Class BookMedia
+ NumberOfPages
+ AuthorName
+ CreatedDate_Internal
+ ModifiedDate_Internal
+ Deleted_Internal

Class MovieMedia
+ Length
+ DirectorName
+ CreatedDate_Internal
+ ModifiedDate_Internal
+ Deleted_Internal
```

Somewhere along the way, between the return from the JsonConverter and the start of the Post method, we lose the new media object, and something declares that our ModelState is Invalid.

ModelState does not appear to be a valid object within the ControllerAction, so I don't even have a way to see what the ModelState errors are?

Commenting out the JsonConverter attribute, bypassing the converter has no substantial effect; the media object remains null.

How can I resolve this issue?

### Edit 1

Updated action method signature to match the route.

### Edit 2 - Added Model Objects

I begin to be suspicious of two things... the (temporary) duplication of the _Internal fields across my models, those will be deleted from our model soon.  The project compiles with the extra bits, but perhaps thats throwing off model validation.

The second thing is the "virtual" person.  I'm not passing that in, nor filling it with the JsonConverter at creation.

### Edit 3 - Solution

I fixed the duplicated _Internal fields, and solved the problem causing my `ModelState` object to be missing (somehow, I'd neglected to derive from controller!).  These however, did not resolve the main issue.

The problem turned out to be the input Json.  The "MediaId" field, in fact.  I'd been passing `null` to it, and as an experiment, I passed it a real value, and suddenly, I've got data flowing through.

Comment: There is a lot here that could be an issue.  I'll take a stab. Can you confirm that the correct Guid 'id' is being passed in on the route?  Your route param is 'Id', yet your controller action is 'id'.

Comment: Hope you are passing the Media object in the request body. Does the request body Json property names match the properties of Media class exactly?.

Comment: @trevorc .. The Id is correct.  It must have been a simple typo as I was transcribing the problem.

Comment: @PradeepKumar .. Yes, I'm passing the media object in the request body.  PropertyNames seem to be right on, and moreover, when I'm stepping through the JsonConverter class, just before it exits (and subsequently gets nulled out), I can see that all the properties in the real "BookMedia" object are filled.  One thing that may be a possibility that I've not yet checked is that there are some meta-data properties of BookMedia that are not present in the Json.  I'm expecting to fill those in with business logic before submission to the database.